# jQuery UI Slider Interference with slick carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

The drag gesture is interfering with the slider from jQuery UI and the [slick carousel plugin](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) (also jQuery). See my example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/65wtmyrb/1/).

**HTML**

```
<div class="stack">
    <div class="boxes">
         <h1>1</h1>
         <div class="slider"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="boxes">
        <h1>2</h1>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.stack').slick({
    centerMode: true,
    centerPadding: '80px',
    arrows: false,
    variableWidth: true,
    dots: true,
    swipeToSlide: true,
    focusOnSelect: true
});

$('.slider').slider({
    max: 100,
    min: 0,
    value: 93
});
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your `<div class="slider">` is a children of `<div class="stack">` you can try to `stopPropagation()` for the events in `slider` which propagates to `slick` carousel provoking it to swipe. This seems tricky however since there is no method to stops and start the `slick` it's an easy approach to achieve your goal. So you can use:

```
$(".slider").on("slide mouseenter mousedown",function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

You can see the result in this working <kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/65wtmyrb/7/)</kbd>

Hope this helps,

Comment: @kolor nice to help you `:)`

Comment: What about slide on mobile phones? Slick ignores stopPropagation().