# jQuery UI draggable inside Slick-slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I need to have a jQuery UI draggable element inside a [Slick-slider](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick). I know that jQuery UI has the handles option http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#handle but I'm not sure how to apply this to the slick-slider.

I found this SO question: [jQuery UI Slider Interference with slick carousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28753503/jquery-ui-slider-interference-with-slick-carousel) but it's using jQuery UI's `slider` option. When I did something similar on my example I was able to disable the slick-slider dragging... But my draggable elements still aren't draggable.

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NateW/u1burczm/

How do I disable dragging on the Slick-slider *only* when it's inside one of my `draggable` elements and still have the `draggable` elements draggable?

---

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper-slider">
  <div> 
    <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
      <p>Drag me around</p>
    </div>
    <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
      <p>and me!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div><h3>1</h3><h3>1</h3><h3>1</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2</h3><h3>2</h3><h3>2</h3><h3>2</h3></div>
  <div><h3>3</h3><h3>3</h3></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.wrapper-slider').slick({
  dots: false,
  infinite: false,
  centerPadding: "20px",
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  adaptiveHeight: true
});

$(function() {
    $( ".draggable-element" ).draggable();
  });

$(".draggable-element").on("draggable mouseenter mousedown",function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: No, unfortunately I haven't been able to get this working the way I'd like... :|

Comment: check the solution below i have added and its working

Comment: @Sam, thank you! It seems to be working great now!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

for that to work you need to unbind the dragstart event registered by slick slider like follow before binding the draggble to element

```
$('.wrapper-slider').slick({
  dots: false,
  infinite: false,
  centerPadding: "20px",
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  adaptiveHeight: true
});

$(function() {
    $('*[draggable!=true]','.slick-track').unbind('dragstart');
    $( ".draggable-element" ).draggable();
  });

$(".draggable-element").on("draggable mouseenter mousedown",function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

here is working jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/samcoolone70/u1burczm/3/