# Dragging external events to FullCalendar from slick slider

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, slick.js

I am using slick slider and fullcalendar together in one of my projects. Full calendar offers a feature of dragging external events to the calendar as shown in this [demo.](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/external-dragging-demo) I am not able to implement the same logic because my events are inside slick slider. Here's a screenshot of what I'm building:[image: screenshot]
And here's the code:

```
<div class="menu-wrap">
    <div class="tab-pane gallery container-fluid" id="favorites">
        <div class="row d-none d-md-block gallery_wrapper">
            <div class="w-100 d-none d-md-block heroSlider-fixed">
                <div class="overlay">
                </div>
                <!-- Slider -->
                <div class="slider responsive six">
                    @for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++)
                        @component('components.menu-plan-componant')

                        @endcomponent
                    @endfor

                </div>
                <!-- control arrows -->
                <div class="prev six-prev">
                    <img src="{{URL::to('assets/images/icon/left_direction.svg')}}"
                         class="chevron-basic">
                </div>
                <div class="next six-next">
                    <img src="{{URL::to('assets/images/icon/right_direction.svg')}}"
                         class="chevron-basic">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

code for slick slider:

```
$('.six').slick({
                    adaptiveHeight: true,
                    prevArrow: $('.six-prev'),
                    nextArrow: $('.six-next'),
                    infinite: false,
                    speed: 300,
                    slidesToShow: 6,
                    slidesToScroll: 6,
                    responsive: [
                        {
                            breakpoint: 1024,
                            settings: {
                                slidesToShow: 6,
                                slidesToScroll: 6,
                                infinite: true,
                                dots: true
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            breakpoint: 600,
                            settings: {
                                slidesToShow: 2,
                                slidesToScroll: 2
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            breakpoint: 480,
                            settings: {
                                slidesToShow: 1,
                                slidesToScroll: 1
                            }
                        }
                        // You can unslick at a given breakpoint now by adding:
                        // settings: "unslick"
                        // instead of a settings object
                    ]
                });
```

And code for full calendar:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                    droppable: true,
                    defaultView: 'Week',
                    header: false,
                    defaultDate: today,
                    navLinks: false, // can click day/week names to navigate views
                    editable: true,
                    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                    schedulerLicenseKey: 'GPL-My-Project-Is-Open-Source',

                    drop: function() {
                        // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
                        if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
                            // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
                            $(this).remove();
                        }
                    },


                    eventRender: function (event, element) {
                        element.find(".fc-event-title").remove();
                        element.find(".fc-event-time").remove();
                        var new_description = '#';
                        element.append(new_description);

                    },
                    now: today,
                    footer: {
                        left: 'promptResource',
                        center: '',
                        right: ''
                    },
                    customButtons: {
                        promptResource: {
                            text: '+ add course',
                            click: function () {
                                var title = prompt('Course name');
                                if (title) {
                                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar(
                                        'addResource',
                                        {title: title},
                                        true // scroll to the new resource?
                                    );
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    views: {
                        Week: {
                            type: 'timeline',
                            duration: {Days: '7'},
                            slotLabelInterval: {hours: 24},
                            slotDuration: {hours: 24},
                        }
                    },
                    resourceLabelText: 'Meal',
                    resourceRender: function (resource, cellEls) {
                        cellEls.on('click', function () {
                            if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete ' + resource.title + '?')) {
                                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeResource', resource);
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    resources: [
                        {id: 'a', title: 'Breakfast', eventColor: 'red'},
                        {id: 'b', title: 'Lunch', eventColor: 'green'},
                        {id: 'c', title: 'Dinner', eventColor: 'orange'},
                        {id: 'd', title: 'Other', eventColor: 'grey'},
                    ],

                    events: [
                        {id: '1', resourceId: 'b', start: today, end: today, title: 'event 1'},
                        {
                            id: '2',
                            resourceId: 'c',
                            start: '2018-04-07T05:00:00',
                            end: '2018-04-07T22:00:00',
                            title: 'event 2'
                        },
                        {id: '3', resourceId: 'd', start: '2018-04-06', end: '2018-04-08', title: 'event 3'},
                        {
                            id: '4',
                            resourceId: 'e',
                            start: '2018-04-07T03:00:00',
                            end: '2018-04-07T08:00:00',
                            title: 'event 4'
                        },
                        {
                            id: '5',
                            resourceId: 'f',
                            start: '2018-04-07T00:30:00',
                            end: '2018-04-07T02:30:00',
                            title: 'event 5'
                        }
                    ],
                    drop: function() {
                        // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
                        if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
                            // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
                            $(this).remove();
                        }
                    }

                });
```

How can I achieve event drag and drop functionality using slick slider and full calendar?

**UPDATE:**
If I make the element inside slick draggable it only applies the region inside slick slider but not outside it. This shown in below screenshot:[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: The external elements need to be `draggable`, as in "jQuery UI draggable". Check out line 15 of the Fullcalendar demo source code: https://codepen.io/pen/?&editors=001

Comment: @FreemanLambda thanks! but the codepen link is empty. could you please check

Comment: Ah sorry, posted the wrong pen link. Just go to the Fullcalendar demo you posted in the question, then click on "Edit in CodePen" button on the very top-right of the page.

Comment: @FreemanLambda yes I followed the same pen but it does not work with slick slider. The element that I want to drag and drop are inside slick slider div thats why I posted this question.

Comment: Perhaps this lead will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29522309/jquery-ui-draggable-inside-slick-slider

Comment: Thanks for the response @FreemanLambda! before posting this question I've already tried to implement the answer from the question you shared in above comment but what it does is, it just limited to the slick slider region, means I am only able to move that particular element inside the slider portion, not into the calendar part. for this, I've added a screenshot in the updated part of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to extend the Fullcalendar Demo into a minimal example including Slick. I have used a `setTimeout` to make sure that Slick has completed its dom manipulations before making anything draggable, but I figure Slick provides some proper async event that tells you exactly when it finished (haven't checked the docs). I think you can adapt this minimal setup into your own application.

https://codepen.io/freemanlambda/pen/MXKPBp?editors=1010

Comment: Thanks! It works, but now the problem is the event is hiding as soon as it leaves the slick slider area. Is there a way we can show the event while dragging. I think it is related to z-index of either slider or the calendar. can you please edit your codepen example?

Comment: Events are hiding not because of z-index, but because the `.slick-list` elment, which wraps all events, has `overflow: hidden`. This hidden overflow is absolutely needed from the carousel to function, but at the same time it makes any content inside of it (events) invisible as soon as content leaves the boundaries of `.slick-list`. Therefore I do not see any possible way to make the dragging of elements visible to the user.

Comment: Also, is it possible to show the recipe image( shown in the screenshot) inside the calendar event? What I want to do is to render images inside full calendar events.

Comment: Yeah it is possible, by tweaking Event Dom during the `eventRender` callback. Here's how: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40266483/fullcalendar-images-as-events